# Can't access object's properties by argument of a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Why array[i].key (where key === "surname") within the function doesn't work,
meanwhile array[i].surname works perfectly?

```js
let objects = [
    { name: 'Jack', surname: 'Jackson' },
    { name: 'Ivar', surname: 'Bjornsson' },
    { name: 'John', surname: 'Mickelson' }
];

function sort (array, key) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        console.log(array[i].key)// Somehow the "key", which is equal to "surname" doesn't work;
        // here will be undefined;
        console.log(array[i].surname)//But here writing 'surname' directly works fine;
        // the correct answer will be there;
        console.log(key)// However, key === surname
    }
}

sort(objects, 'surname');
```

Comment: `objects` doesn't have a property `key`. What do you expect `array[i].key` to return?

Comment: Can you point to a line of code in which you’d expect a key named `key` to be added to the objects in question…?

Comment: Here "sort(objects, 'surname')" I was trying to run the code, expecting my second argument 'surname' to replace 'key'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to access the property with square brackets:

```js
let objects = [
    { name: 'Jack', surname: 'Jackson' },
    { name: 'Ivar', surname: 'Bjornsson' },
    { name: 'John', surname: 'Mickelson' }
];

function sort (array, key) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        console.log(array[i][key])// Somehow the "key", which is equal to "surname" doesn't work;
        // here will be undefined;
        console.log(array[i].surname)//But here writing 'surname' directly works fine;
        // the correct answer will be there;
        console.log(key)// However, key === surname
    }
}

sort(objects, 'surname');
```

This

```
array[i].key
```

is equivalent to

```
array[i]['key']
```

Comment: You are legend!